# How to make node.js program wait for a PNG to parse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing

I am writing a project which requires me to load a lot of low resolution PNGs (~10k) to train my neural network. This is my code

NOTE: **This project uses 'pngjs' module**

```
for(var i = 0;i < 100;i++){
var input_dir = dirs[i];
console.log('file number: ', i);
fs.createReadStream(input_dir).pipe(new PNG({
          filterType: 4,}))
        .on("parsed", function(){
          console.log(input_dir);
          for(var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
              var idx = (this.width * y + x) << 2;
              // invert color
              this.data[idx] = 255 - this.data[idx];
              this.data[idx + 1] = 255 - this.data[idx + 1];
              this.data[idx + 2] = 255 - this.data[idx + 2];
              var sum = this.data[idx]+this.data[idx + 1]+this.data[idx + 2];
              sum /= 3;
              arr.push(sum);
            }
          }
          console.log(arr);
        });
}
```

After execution, I a ton of `file number:`  in the terminal, after which all the images show up.
Any way to make the program wait for the image to parse?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createReadStream will run asynchronously each time that you call it, you could wrap it in a function that returns a promise, then await each one of those promises with Promise.all.

```
function readStreamPromise(input_dir){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fs.createReadStream(input_dir)
             .pipe(new PNG({filterType: 4,}))
             .on("parsed", () => {
                 // do parsing logic
                  resolve()
             });
        }
    }
```

then do something like

```
await Promise.all(dirs.map((inputDir) => {
    return readStreamPromise(inputDir)
})
```

of course this would need to be inside of an async function if you use the await

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would like to await its loading phase before proceeding. Luckily there is a keyword for that; namely `await`. It must be paired with `async`. Check it out.

Edit: The idea in general is that you would make an array of so-called Promises (related to async and await); one Promise for each image. You can then await the completion of all these asynchronous Promises, i.e. when *all* images are loaded. And after that you can do what you want while still having all images load asynchronously in beforehand. (Hint: Promise.all)

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Edited with an explanation.